# Generating Random decimal values in Jaseci

Tags: jaseci

How do we generate random floating-point values in jaseci, similar random.random() in python?

```
walker init{
    rand.seed(4);
    num = rand.rand();
    std.out(num);
}
```

the above code doesn't work in Jaseci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Jaseci version `1.3.5.14` and above, the `rand` standard Jac library support `rand.uniform(min, max);` which will return a random float value between `min` and `max` that could be either integers or floats.

Also note that this version release include `std.round` action. The following code should work and illustrate this capability:

```
walker rand_float_round {
    rand.seed(1);
    report std.round(rand.uniform(2.3, 2.4), 3);
    report std.round(rand.uniform(2, 3), 3);
}
```